# How does a RandomForestClassifier in sklearn use sample weights?

Tags: random-forest, sample-weighting

How does a RandomForestClassifier in sklearn use sample weights?

1. Are sample weights applied when Random Forest bootstraps?
2. Are sample weights applied when model fitting i.e. when training the loss function or deciding splits and reduction in impurity?
3. Are sample weights used in model evaluation metrics - precision, recall and accuracy of a binary classifier?

I believe that it is applied in the first two cases but not for the third one but want more clarity on how sklearn uses sample weight for random forests under the hood?